# Getting around Cape Verde islands from Sal

Tags: ferries, cape-verde

I will land in Sal and, as I'm staying for only 5 days, I would like to visit a couple more islands. I understand that the time is short and moving across them is not easy and, in any case, easier by plane.

What islands are reachable by ferry, if any, and with sites that make it worth the trip? Where should I stay to make the most of my visit?

Comment: I made a few changes so that your question is less broad, and it not asking for opinions and, therefore, less likely to be closed for that reason. Hopefully, you're okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

[CapeVerde.com](http://www.capeverde.com/travel-tips/ferries.html) offers the following details on inter-island transportation:

> **Ferries between the Islands of Cape Verde (National ferries)**
>
> Only some of the ferries between the islands have a regular schedule. For island connections that are not listed below, travellers should ask for information on site. If a schedule is announced, be prepared for delays that could last from hours to days.
>
> Ferries are especially suited for visiting the islands have no functioning airport (Santo Antao and Brava).
>
> For the islands have a functioning airport, we recommend the option with the aircraft - available on our page for [Cape Verde domestic flights](http://www.capeverde.com/holiday-travel/domestic-flights.html).
>
> **ARMAS Ferry "Mar d'Canal"**
>   The ARMAS Mar d'Canal ferry travels every day between São Vicente and Santo Antão. The travel time is 60 minutes. Please always arrive 35 minutes before departure. The ferry is very punctual and removes the stairs 10 minutes before departure.
>
> Ticketprice: 800 Escudos
>
> Ticket sales in Mindelo directly at the harbour building 7.00 a.m. - 12.00 a.m. and 2.00 p.m. - 4.00 p.m.
>
> Ticket sales in Porto Novo inside the harbour building.
>
> **Mindelo - Porto Novo**
>   Mon-Sun at 8.00 a.m.
>   Mon-Sat at 3.00 p.m.
>   **Porto Novo - Mindelo**
>   Mon-Sat at 10.00 a.m.
>   Mon-Sun at 5.00 p.m.
>
> **POLARIS Ferry "Interilhas"**
>   The "Inter Ilhas" ferry travels every day between São Vicente and Santo Antão. The travel time is 50 minutes. Please always arrive 25 minutes before departure. The ferry is very punctual and removes the stairs 10 minutes before departure.>
>   Ticketprice: 800 Escudos
>
> Ticket sales in Mindelo directly in "Cais Marítima" 6.00 a.m. - 12.00 a.m. and 3.00 p.m. - 7.00 p.m.
>
> Ticket sales in Porto Novo at Harbour entry
>
> **Mindelo - Porto Novo**
>   Mon-Sat at 7.00 a.m.
>   Mon-Sun at 4.00 p.m. *
>   **Porto Novo - Mindelo**
>   Mon-Sat at 9.00 a.m.
>   Mon-Sun at 6.00 p.m. *
>
> - Every two weeks it travels to São Nicolau on Thursday afternoon, so on this day there is no transport with this ferry to and from Santo Antão
>
> **[CVFastferry](http://cvfastferry.com/v1/)**
>   This fast ferry operates Santiago - Fogo - Brava
>
> With the partly state-owned company CVFastferry you can now travel between Santiago, Fogo and Brava.
>
> Current schedules and ticket purchase: [cvfastferry.com](http://cvfastferry.com)

Wikipedia [Getting around Cape Verde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Cape_Verde) provides a less detailed overview but it too notes that timetables in Cape Verde are not to be taken too seriously - don't be too surprised if that boat departs ahead of schedule.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at capeverde.com too and it is not that helpful. Maybe I'll try to write to them and ask for the naval routes that aren't there.

Comment: @Francesco my Cape Verdean friends tell me it's very hit and miss, even with 'scheduled' boats/ferries. Verdeans just go to a port, if there's a boat, they catch it, if not.... :D